# RegEx to replace variable quantity of characters with single character

Tags: javascript, regex

Given this string

```
var d = 'The;Quick;;Brown;Fox;;;;;;Jumps';
```

What RegEx would I need to convert to this string:

```
'The,Quick,Brown,Fox,Jumps'
```

I need to replace 1-n characters (e.g. ';') with a single character (e.g. ',').

And because I know that sometimes you like to know "what are you *trying* to accomplish??"
I need to condition a string list of values that can be separated with a combination of different methods:

```
'The ,     Quick \r\n Brown  , \r\n Fox    ,Jumps,'
```

My approach was to convert all known delimiters to a standard character (e..g ';') and then replace that with the final desired ', ' delimiter

Comment: Have you tried: `string.replace(/;+/g, ',');`?

Comment: Yep, it was the + quantifier I missed, thank. I knew that at a time... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as Josh Crozier says, you can use

```
d = d.replace(/;+/g, ',');
```

You can also to the whole thing in one operation with something like

```
d = d.replace(/[,; \r\n]+/g, ',');
```

The `[,; \r\n]+` part will find groups that are made of commas, semicolons, spaces etc.. Then the replace will replace them all with a single comma. You can add any other characters you want to treat as delimiters in with the brackets.

EDIT: actually, it's probably better to use something like this. The `\s` will match any whitespace character.

```
d.replace(/[,;\s]+/g, ',');
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
d.replace(/[;]+/g, ',')
```

It just replaces all group of semicolons together for a comma